# Tromsø for the Aurora Borealis in March

Tags: norway, tromso, auroras

Is March too late for seeing the Aurora Borealis (northern lights) in Tromsø, Norway? There is a new moon on the 21st and I would be looking to go around then.

I'm aware it's weather and light dependent hence why I would go around the time of a new moon.

Comment: Yup! So it looks like the new moon in March is pushing it a little, given the price of getting there id rather centre myself in the 'window' a little more. So I've just squeezed a trip in near the new moon in February for four days.

Comment: how about an answer from yourself with some photos, so people know what Feb was like?

Comment: It's on my to do list ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tromso) Tromsø is in the "aurora belt" between 6pm and midnight and it is dark before 6pm between mid-october and mid-march. It goes on to say that the best time to visit for the aurora is december to mid/late march. It seems that you are just on the edge of the best circumstances with the 21st of march.

Answer (score 11):

We stayed in Tromsø on december (2009) and we were really lucky according to what some locals tell us. As @froderik stated, they explained that the Aurora is common from december to march and rare rest of the year. We stayed 3 days the first week of december and took these photos that were "great for this epoch":

[image]

[image]

Not very spectacular, but good for early december :)